# Em que momento o Entity Framework executa a query de um IQueryable?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Estou desenvolvendo um método para uma API que consiste no seguinte: buscar todas as avaliações de determinado cliente e, caso seja especificado, limitar a quantidade de registros que será retornada.

Por exemplo:

```
public IEnumerable<Avaliacao> GetAvaliacoes(int idCliente, [FromUri]uint limit = 0)
{
    var query = contexto.Avaliacoes.Include(x => x.Notas)
                              .Where(a => a.IdCliente == idCliente)
                              .OrderByDescending(x => x.DataRegistro);

    if (limit != 0)
       return query.Take((int)limit);

    return query;
}
```

O que eu pensei aqui foi o seguinte: ao fazer `var query = *consulta*` eu estaria apenas **criando** a `query`, que só será executada posteriormente (com `ToList()` ou, neste caso, ao retornar os dados).

Isso está certo ou a *query* é executada naquele primeiro momento do exemplo?

Comment: Relacionado (*en*): http://stackoverflow.com/q/2678405/4190610

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Em resumo, no momento em que é `IQueryable` é convertido para `IEnumerable`.

Detalhando um pouco mais, os seguintes métodos provocam essa conversão:

- [`ToList()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx);
- [`AsEnumerable()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb335435(v=vs.110).aspx);
- [`Count()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb338038(v=vs.110).aspx);
- [`Any()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb337697(v=vs.110).aspx);
- [`First()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb291976(v=vs.110).aspx);
- [`FirstOrDefault()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx);
- [`Single()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb155325(v=vs.110).aspx);
- [`SingleOrDefault()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb342451(v=vs.110).aspx);
- [`GetEnumerator()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.collections.ienumerable.getenumerator(v=vs.110).aspx);
- etc.

[Veja mais alguns dos métodos aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.linq.enumerable(v=vs.110).aspx).

E estes não provocam essa conversão:

- [`Where()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb535040(v=vs.100).aspx);
- [`OrderBy()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb549264(v=vs.110).aspx);
- [`ThenBy()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.linq.queryable.thenby(v=vs.110).aspx);
- [`Skip()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb357513(v=vs.110).aspx);
- [`Take()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb300906(v=vs.110).aspx);
- etc.

[Veja todos os métodos aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.linq.queryable_methods(v=vs.110).aspx).

> Isso está certo ou a *query* é executada naquele primeiro momento do exemplo?

Não. Ela é executada aqui:

```
return query;
```

No caso, você está convertendo algo que é `IQueryable` em `IEnumerable`. Aliás, se você mudasse o tipo de retorno para `IQueryable`, a *query* não seria executada.

Seu raciocínio de adiar a produção da enumeração está certo, tanto que não há problema algum em fazer o seguinte:

```
var query = db.Entidades.Where(...);
query = query.Where(...);
if (condicao) query = query.Where(...);
```