# Erro ao utilizar Split dentro do Select

Tags: c#, linq

Por que a exceção abaixo ocorre ao usar `Split` dentro de um `Select` em um `IQueryable`?

> The LINQ expression node type 'ArrayIndex' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.

Eu já consegui resolver o problema usando `ToList` e fazendo o `Select` com `Split` nele, mas gostaria de entender qual é o motivo do problema.

Assim ocorre exceção:

```
var retorno = entities.tabela.Where(x => x.coluna1 == null)
    .Select(x => new { Campo1 = x.coluna1, Campo2 = x.coluna2 });

retorno = retorno.Select(x => new { x.Campo1, Campo2 = x.Campo2.Split(' ')[0] });
```

Assim funciona:

```
var retorno = entities.tabela.Where(x => x.coluna1 == null)
    .Select(x => new { Campo1 = x.coluna1, Campo2 = x.coluna2 }).ToList();

retorno = retorno.Select(x => new { x.Campo1, Campo2 = x.Campo2.Split(' ')[0] }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Eu já consegui resolver o problema usando `ToList` e fazendo o `Select` com `Split` nele, mas gostaria de entender qual é o motivo do problema.

[O motivo começa nesta explicação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/113634/em-que-momento-o-ef-executa-a-query-de-um-iqueryable/113636#113636). Sem resolver a enumeração, seu `IQueryable` tenta passar o `Split` para um equivalente em SQL, o que não existe.

Há de se entender que `DbSet` implementa tanto `IQueryable` quanto `IEnumerable`. Ao chamar `ToList()`, você pede ao LINQ para resolver a enumeração, e assim ele executa o SQL. Como o `Split` no segundo exemplo ficou para a coleção já resolvida, o `Select` atua sobre a coleção em memória, e não mais geração de SQL.

Comment: Que legal! Eu pensava que as queries eram executadas sempre que eu usava `Select` ou `Where`. Isso já explica outro problema que tive quando tentei fazer Join entre `IQueryable` e `List`.

Comment: @DanielDutra Você ver mais detalhes, [na resposta aqui (que também é do Cigano)](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/113634/18246)

Comment: @jbueno o Cigano já _linkou_ ela na resposta, vlw!

Comment: *Ouch*. Não tinha visto, obrigado por avisar.

Comment: Só me confirmem uma coisa que eu não acho que vale uma pergunta nova: fazer um `foreach` em `new List<string>().Select(...)` e `new List<string>().Select(...).ToList()` dá no mesmo, né? Neste caso o `Select` é realmente executado quando eu "chamo ele", certo?

Comment: Ops, na verdade, é sim a mesma coisa. Não tinha atentado que o exemplo usava uma lista. Se você fizer o `Select` em uma lista, sim é praticamente a mesma coisa. A única diferença é que sem o `ToList()` a iteração será feita num `IEnumerable`, com o `ToList()` ela é feita numa lista. Aliás, eu acho que isso vale sim uma pergunta.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/129779/foreach-em-select-e-list !