# Foreach em Select e List

Tags: c#, foreach

Descobri recentemente que existe uma grande diferença entre fazer algumas operações, como `Select` e `Where`, em `Queryable` e objetos enumerados, como `Enumerable` e `List`. [Nesta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/129590/erro-ao-utilizar-split-dentro-do-select) e [nesta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/113634/em-que-momento-o-ef-executa-a-query-de-um-iqueryable) pergunta.

Sabendo disso, fiquei curioso para saber se existe diferenças entre iterar valores de uma `List` e iterar valores direto de um `Select`.
Eu vi no debug que quando só faço `Select` estou iterando sobre um `{System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator<string, string>}`.

Quando eu faço `Where` ou `Select` em uma lista a operação é executada no instante que o método é chamado ou só é executada quando eu acesso os itens ou uso `ToList()`?

Além disso, existe alguma diferença de performance entre os dois casos?
É mais fácil iterar sobre uma `List` ou é mais custoso transformar em `List` para depois iterar?

Diferença disso:

```
var lista = new List<string>() { ... };
var listaFiltrada = lista.Select(x => x).ToList();

foreach (var item in listaFiltrada) { ... }
```

Para isso:

```
var lista = new List<string>() { ... };
var selectFiltrado = lista.Select(x => x);

foreach (var item in selectFiltrado) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Quando eu faço `Where` ou `Select` em uma lista a operação é executada no instante que o método é chamado ou só é executada quando eu acesso os itens ou uso `ToList()`?

Considerando LINQ to SQL ou Entity Framework, apenas no momento da conversão para `IEnumerable`, ou seja, `ToList()`.

O que `Select` faz é gerar um iterador que servirá como um filtro na próxima operação, como `ToList()`, por exemplo. No caso de `IQueryable`, este filtro do `Select` será interpretado como as colunas de uma seleção em SQL. Por exemplo:

```
var listaExemplo = context.Entidades.Select(x => new { x.Coluna1, x.Coluna2, x.Coluna3 }).ToList();
```

Será gerado um SQL assim:

```
SELECT COLUNA1, COLUNA2, COLUNA3 FROM ENTIDADES
```

Para objetos em memória, `Select` devolve este objeto especial (`WhereSelectListIterator<string, string>`). Ele é um iterador, assim como `GetEnumerator` também devolve um iterador.

Aqui:

```
var listaFiltrada = lista.Select(x => x).ToList();

foreach (var item in listaFiltrada) { ... }
```

Você resolve a enumeração e passa para o `foreach` uma lista materializada, enquanto que aqui:

```
var selectFiltrado = lista.Select(x => x);

foreach (var item in selectFiltrado) { ... }
```

Você indica que `selectFiltrado` será um enumerador (iterador) cuja resolução transformará cada objeto da enumeração no predicado de dentro de `Select` (no exemplo, devolver o próprio objeto sem alteração). A lista, portanto, não se materializa.

O primeiro exemplo tem utilidade quando:

- Você precisa obter algo da lista como uma lista antes do `foreach`;
- Você precisa resolver uma *query* SQL e só depois manipular o resultado.

O segundo exemplo tem utilidade quando:

- A lista não precisa ser materializada antes do `foreach`.