# Uso de LINQ para fazer consulta em uma coleção

Tags: c#, sql

sobre min: Eu venho do JAVA e recentemente estou aprendendo c#, porem eu estou com uma duvida em relação ao uso do LINQ.
Muitos tutorias falam da maravilha que é o LINQ porem eu até agora não consigo entender a sua utilidade.
Olhem esse código abaixo:

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Pessoa p1 = new Pessoa() { nome= "Fulano", idade = 10};
        Pessoa p2 = new Pessoa() { nome = "Fulano2", idade = 18 };

        List<Pessoa> listaDePessoa = new List<Pessoa>();
        listaDePessoa.Add(p1);
        listaDePessoa.Add(p2);

        var consulta = from p in listaDePessoa
              where p.idade > 10
              select p;

    }

}

public class Pessoa
{
    public string nome;
    public int idade;
}
```

Não seria mais fácil fazer uma consulta direto do banco? no JAVA eu faria isso usando o JDBC.

```
select * from tb_pessoas
where idade > 10
```

Talvez eu só estou pensando em relação ao banco de dados se for isso me deem alguns outros usos do LINQ.

Comment: não comece comparando linguagens isso é um grande erro, cada uma tem a sua forma e `LINQ` tem várias divisões o que você acabou de fazer é `Linq to object` existe o `Linq to SQL` (e muito mais ...), precisa dar uma lida nos conceitos.

Comment: Esse [**link**](http://raphaelcardoso.com.br/conceitos-introducao-ao-linq-parte-1/) já vai ter dar uma pequena visão ou/e [**link**](http://www.devmedia.com.br/introducao-ao-linq/22769)

Answer (score 2):

> Não seria mais fácil fazer uma consulta direto do banco?

Não, porque o LINQ não serve só para formular consultas SQL. É um recurso muito mais poderoso.

[LINQ, conforme artigo da Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query), "é um componente do Microsoft .NET que adiciona funcionalidades de consulta em algumas linguagens de programação .NET". Isto quer dizer que podemos utilizar essa funcionalidade de consulta sobre qualquer objeto em .NET em qualquer linguagem de programação cujo código seja gerenciado (*managed*).

Suponha um objeto `Cerveja`:

```
public class Cerveja 
{
    public String Nome { get; set; }
    public String Tipo { get; set; }
    public decimal Preco { get; set; }
}
```

Suponha uma lista de cervejas:

```
var cervejas = new List<Cerveja> 
{
    new Cerveja { Nome = "Budweiser", Tipo = "American Lager", Preco = 3M },
    new Cerveja { Nome = "Heineken", Tipo = "Pale Lager", Preco = 3.5M },
    new Cerveja { Nome = "Stella Artois", Tipo = "Pilsner", Preco = 3.3M },
};
```

Adiciono o recurso de LINQ ao meu código:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Posso pesquisar a lista usando uma sintaxe de consulta. Por exemplo, se quero saber se existe uma cerveja com o nome "Budweiser":

```
var bud = cervejas.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Nome == "Budweiser");
```

A pesquisa ocorre em memória e retorna um objeto. Se não existisse a cerveja cujo nome é "Budweiser" na lista, o retorno seria um objeto nulo.

Se eu quiser todas as cervejas mais caras que 3 reais, posso usar:

```
var cervejasCaras = cervejas.Where(c => c.Preco > 3M).ToList();
```

### Sobre seu exemplo

Esse exemplo não vai ao banco de dados. Assim como no meu exemplo, você apenas faz uma operação de pesquisa em memória. Para ir ao banco de dados, você precisaria conectar seu código a uma fonte de dados. O recurso que faz isso se chama [LINQ to SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx). [Um exemplo de uso completo está aqui](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26657/Simple-LINQ-to-SQL-in-C).

Diferentemente do LINQ puro, o LINQ to SQL monta uma consulta através da acumulação de predicados em um objeto que implementa [`IQueryable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb351562(v=vs.110).aspx), sendo `T` uma classe que representa um registro do banco de dados na linguagem .NET que você está utilizando. Essa consulta é executada apenas no momento em que o código pede a materialização da lista ([falo disso aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/113634/em-que-momento-o-entity-framework-executa-a-query-de-um-iqueryable/113636#113636)).

O LINQ to SQL recebeu uma primeira atualização, chamada [LINQ to Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb386964(v=vs.110).aspx), em que o banco de dados ao qual o código se conecta é tratado como um contexto de objetos ([`ObjectContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext(v=vs.110).aspx)) e cada entidade (tabela, no caso de um banco de dados relacional) é mapeada como um [`ObjectSet<TEntity>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd412719(v=vs.110).aspx), sendo `TEntity` uma classe cujas propriedades são as colunas (ou campos) de cada registro de dados.

Essa atualização se transformou em um *framework* bastante usado atualmente chamado [Entity Framework](https://www.asp.net/entity-framework), mais maduro, otimizado, que possui capacidades adicionais ao LINQ to Entities, como a capacidade de geração de um banco de dados através de código e o suporte incremental a migrações de esquema de dados. Ou seja, se você está escrevendo seu código e modelando as entidades, o banco de dados acompanha essas alterações na modelagem através de um recurso conhecido como **migrações** (ou *Migrations*). [Temos uma *tag* aqui no site apenas falando deste *framework*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/entity-framework/info).

Answer (score 0):

Linq é uma linguagem de abstração de query's onde tem o foco em facilitar a escrita de consultas.

Utilizar linq visa padronizar todas suas consultas feitas no c#, e esta é sua principal característica, a microsoft disponibiliza [este conteudo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd890987.aspx) dizendo algumas razões do porque utilizar linq não só linq-to-sql, mas como padrão de consulta a dados.