# Dúvida na Declaração de Tipo de objeto - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Preciso de ajuda na definição para a correta declaração de classe

Segue meu código:

```
public void BuscaOcorremcias()
{
    //Op 01 - Declarando um IList da Model
    IList<Ocorrencia> ocorrencias = null;
    //Op 02 - Declarando um DbSet
    System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MoradaWeb.Models.Ocorrencia> ocorrencias = null;

    ocorrencias = db.Ocorrencia.Include("Pessoa").Where(c => c.status == true);

    if (MinhaRegradeNegocio)
        ocorrencias = ocorrencias.Where(c => c.Pessoa == PessoaLogada);
}
```

//Meu Context

```
public class MeuContext : DbContext
{
    public MoradaWebContext() : base("name=MinhaConnectionString")
    {   ...   }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Models.Ocorrencia> Ocorrencia { get; set; }
}
```

O erro que dá com as duas opções acima (no comentário do código) é este:

> Cannot implicititly convert type...

Não estou sabendo qual tipo declarar para que eu possa manter a condição de aplicar um Where a mais se for preciso. Neste caso quero fazer o segundo where dentro da própria coleção que já foi buscada no banco.

Comment: Declare como `var ocorrencias = db.Ocorrencia.Include("Pessoa").Where(c => c.status == true);` e veja o tipo definido posicionando o cursor do mouse sobre a variável ocorrencias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É `IQueryable` o que você precisa.

Se estiver selecionando apenas o `DbSet` (`db.Ocorrencia`, no exemplo) é também necessário chamar o método `AsQueryable` porque o tipo dele é justamente `DbSet`. A partir do primeiro `Include`, `Where` ou afins o tipo retornado passa a ser um `IQueryable`.

Você pode ver mais detalhes, [nesta minha pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/113634/18246).

```
IQueryable<Ocorrencia> ocorrencias = db.Ocorrencia.Include("Pessoa")
                                       .Where(c => c.status == true);

if (MinhaRegradeNegocio)
    ocorrencias = ocorrencias.Where(c => c.Pessoa == PessoaLogada);
```

Também é possível usar `var` e deixar que o tipo seja definido automaticamente.

Comment: jbueno, seu link foi muito útil. Obrigado. Consegui resolver indo direto para o IEnumerable<T>

Comment: @BrunoHeringer Indo direto pro IEnumerable você traz todos os registros para a memória antes do segundo filtro

Comment: Boa observação... vlw demais...