# Não lista dados do banco corretamente na View asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Os dados foram inserido no banco, mas na View não mostra um dos campo.

Eu verifiquei no SQL Server e está tudo certo, mas o campo nome retorna vazio na *view*

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<MovimentacaoVM> lispedido;
    using (Db db = new Db())
    {
        lispedido = db.Movimentacao.ToArray()
                      .OrderBy(x => x.MovimentacaoId)
                      .Select(x => new MovimentacaoVM(x)).ToList();
    }

    return View(lispedido);           
}
```

Código da view:

```
@model IEnumerable<PraticaNtoN.Models.MovimentacaoVM>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Criar")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>

        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProdutoNome)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ClienteNome)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DataCriacao)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProdutoNome)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ClienteNome)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DataCriacao)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.MovimentacaoId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.MovimentacaoId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.MovimentacaoId })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Método `MovimentacaoVM`

```
public MovimentacaoVM(Movimentacao row)
{
    MovimentacaoId = row.MovimentacaoId;
    ClienteId = row.ClienteId;
    DataCriacao = row.DataCriacao;
    ProdutoId = row.ProdutoId;
    ProdutoNome = row.ClienteNome;
    ProdutoNome = row.ProdutoNome;
}
```

Comment: Pode postar o código da _view_?

Comment: Quando fala em "campo nome" você se refere a ProdutoNome ou ClienteNome?

Comment: ao clienteNome todos os campos estão preenchidos la no sql server manager, eu verifiquei, mas na hora de mostrar na view vem todos os campos menos o nome do cliente

Comment: Poste também o código do método `MovimentacaoVM`

Comment: Cara, posta o código do método que eu falei ali em cima.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiramente uma dica: não faça a ordernação dos dados em memória a não ser que tenha um motivo para isto. Claro que isso não é uma receita que você deva seguir cegamente, mas na maioria das vezes delegar a ordenação para o banco de dados é muito mais performático.

Você pode ver mais detalhes sobre isto em: [Em que momento o Entity Framework executa a query de um IQueryable?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/113634/18246)

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<MovimentacaoVM> lispedido;
    using (Db db = new Db())
    {
        lispedido = db.Movimentacao.OrderBy(x => x.MovimentacaoId) //Remova o ToArray()
                      .Select(x => new MovimentacaoVM(x)).ToList();
    }

    return View(lispedido);           
}
```

Segundo, seu erro é bem simples. Veja o método **`MovimentacaoVM`**, que é o método que faz a seleção dos itens

```
public MovimentacaoVM(Movimentacao row)
{
    MovimentacaoId = row.MovimentacaoId;
    ClienteId = row.ClienteId;
    DataCriacao = row.DataCriacao;
    ProdutoId = row.ProdutoId;
    //ProdutoNome = row.ClienteNome;  // <----- Isso está errado
    ClienteNome = row.ClienteNome;  // <------- Deveria ser isto
    ProdutoNome = row.ProdutoNome;
}
```

Comment: Meu deus como nao vi isso, que vergonha hahahah.. Obrigado, é q estou fazendo N pra N .Agora está funcionando